# Arqade Community SkyBlock

Tags: discussion, minecraft

## Please read the following notice

The Arqade SkyBlock server has not received enough traffic to really justify keeping it around. It is a really fun server, so I'd never let the map go to waste. It will be going down very shortly, and the map will be going up (spawn not included). The WorldEdit schematic of the Arqade logo will also be going up. Thank you for playing, but it is no longer sustainable to justify to anyone. The old post is now in a code block.

```
We're proud to announce that the un-official SkyBlock server for Arqade has launched into beta! This is a **SkyBlock** server, and each player has his/her own SkyBlock. *There is no normal world, currently. We plan to release one soon, though.*

**Connect at:** `sky.stackgaming.com`.  
 This server is not whitelisted.  

To start your skyblock type `/island`. If you mess up badly, you can type `/island restart` to reset your island and start over. If you end up making obsidian by accident, right click on the obsidian block with lava.

----

Vote for our [community advertisement](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5602/community-promotion-ads-2013/7171#7171)!

Moderation status is done by reputation.  
2k rep will earn you the rank of [TrialMod], which allows you to kick and tempban players.  
3k rep will earn you the rank of [ServerModerator], which allows you to kick, ban, fly, and tempban players.  
A Diamond will earn you the rank of [ArqadeMod], which allows you to pretty much everything.  


***Moderation Commands:***  

`/kick user` will kick the user specified.  
`/ban user` will ban the user specified.  
`/tempban user h(our)/d(ay)/w(eek)` will ban the user for the time specified.  
`/fly` will activate fly mode.
***This will serve as a verification thread. To verify your profile and gain access to the upcoming survival world, leave a community wiki answer proving that you are a reputable SE user. This is to prevent griefing of the main world, as we will heavily shame you if you grief. :)***
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Tbh, the community add doesn't look that good.

Comment: @Lyrion Oh, I know. I need to work on it. Expect an update next week :)

Comment: Also, you forgot the most important thing... The IP.

Comment: 14 5 -499. Also creepers

Comment: @jeffreylin_ :P I added it

Comment: @jeffreylin_ Erm, your edit is, well, confusing...

Comment: What do the ranks mean?

Comment: @OrigamiRobot Updated, again :)

Comment: Can somebody work on a new community ad? I'm caught up with other work right now.

Comment: I've updated the server to 1.5.2

Comment: Is the toplist not working? `/island top` doesn't show any rankings, and I'm pretty sure my sweet 35th-level sky tower of doom should make the cut.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I'll check it out now.

Comment: We're getting a lot of players who don't know what the server's about (who then make an island and then abandon it). I don't think they're arriving via this page. Is `enable-query` on in the server properties? If so, the server is probably being listed on public server lists.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie It is listed on PlanetMinecraft, but that's all.

Comment: There's a guy called 'Ladimus' showing up as @CAKEMAN@, who is generally making a bit of a nuisance of himself but claiming to be an op :/ is he legit?

Comment: He actually isn't an op on this server, but he does have an admin account on another server run with the same IP. (different port)

Comment: Well like I said, he was being what could only be described as a nuisance, and he certainly had op powers and was using creative mode to fly around and bother me. Also as @SevenSidedDie said, there are a lot of people who aren't from SE turning up who simply don't seem to know what's going on

Comment: @AliceRees Allright, thanks for clarifying. I'll talk to him today.

Comment: The toplist is still broken: it's showing something, but it hasn't updated since you fixed it, so it's "frozen" somehow.

Comment: **We are currently suffering a DoS attack on our servers. We will keep everyone updated.**

Comment: The DoS attack appears to be over, and all outages should have stopped now. Thanks!

Comment: This is a shame :( It was fun but I got disheartened when animals just wouldn't spawn >.< However I thought there was mention of a survival server in planning. This still happening?

Comment: @AliceRees There was going to be a world for that on the server, but that's going down with it :(

Comment: @IanCarroll dang :(

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Server Changelog:

May 9th:
- Fixed `/island top`

May 2nd:
- Updated server to 1.5.2

April 30th:
- Updated listing with more detail
- Added change log
- Added staff rank detail

Comment: ***Honestly. Honestly. Honestly. You downvoted THE CHANGELOG.***

Comment: It's not an appropriate place to put it, this is not a forum. Edit your original post.

Comment: And plus, who uses a changelog?!?

Answer (score 1):

Just saying, it's nice, but needs more work.

Starting area completely blew up, thanks to the work of some mischievous individuals (namely, Creepers).

I've found a village not too far from spawn to settle down, rather than residing in a locked up prison SKyblock.

That is all.

Comment: I'm not sure how you got out of spawn without some sort of hack. It's *SkyBlock*, if you don't want to play skyblock then go on `mine.stackgaming.com` or some other server

Comment: When I first joined the server, part of it was already blown up.  I assumed either a creeper blew up that part (triggered by another player).

Comment: I know you set up the region to be a "cannot destroy", and trying to destroy the block myself was impossible, but creepers which exploded could.  That also explains the hole in the wool wall near spawn

Comment: I think if you set up the spawn to be up in the air, it'll prevent a lot of mobs from actually being able to destroy it.  As well as kill players trying to get out of spawn (they'll fall to their deaths)

Comment: Ah ha, ok. Sorry for accusing you of hacking :P

Answer (score 0):

My minecraft handle is `eggdropsoap` and I'm an Arqade user.

Comment: I'll add you as a ServerModerator. :)

Comment: Also, can you add this as a community wiki post, per the instructions? Thanks :)

Comment: @Ian I can reed gud! Done. :)

Comment: I promoted u 2 srvrmderator

Comment: @SevenSidedDie off topic, but why don't we see you on the FTB server?

Comment: @jeffreylin Only so much time for too many interests. Skyblock is nice in bite-sized diversions, which is about what's left after family and the tabletop RPG campaign I'm planning/running lately take their shares of attention.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie That's too bad. Judging from your answers you seem to be pretty good at it.

Comment: @IanCarroll, what can ServerMods do? Since `/help` is locked down I can't figure out what my actual role or powers are.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie `3k rep will earn you the rank of [ServerModerator], which allows you to kick, ban, fly, and tempban players.`

Comment: I'm also on the server right now :)

Comment: @Ian Ok! Clarifying the question: what *should* ServerMods be doing, what are our rules for when kicks/bans/tempbans are to be used, and… is there a command reference so that I can use those correctly? Flying isn't clear, for example: double-jumping doesn't do it, so what does?

Comment: `/fly` will activate/deactivate your fly mode, `/tempban user 1(h(our)/d(ay)/w(eek)` Do not include the content in () while issuing the command. Flying is at your will, but don't go flying around killing people, please.

Comment: `/ban user` will, well, ban them. `/kick user` will kick the user.

Comment: Added a command reference for your convinence.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie but then why aren't you on Minecraft Talk (chat)?

Comment: @jeffreylin_ I find the chat rooms to be the wrong size of bite size. I end up looking in, making a comment, and then forgetting about it again for hours or days.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie you could pin it on Firefox or chrome and look back every now and then.

Comment: @jeffreylin_ Experience shows it just doesn't happen. Chat is a communication method that fits into idle time that I just don't have anymore. I computer now in concentrated bursts of activity that doesn't suit chat.

Comment: Hmm... too bad.

Answer (score 0):

I'm `shanodin` on Minecraft and I am a real person who plays on the server.

Answer (score -1):

Great idea! A few tips from one server admin to another:

- Can you put a bit more detail about what's going on here in your post? The pictures show some kind of skyblock, but is that it? Does each player get their own, or is there just one?
- Why would I want to play this? Is it a 'famous' map, or one you've made yourself for the community? If others have played it, are there any LP's I can watch on YouTube to get a flavour?
- Either turn mob-griefing off, or make sure creepers can't destroy spawn ;-)
- Is the server whitelisted? If so where/who should I apply to for access? If it's not whitelisted, what (if any?) protection is on the server? Who are the ops?

Best of luck with this!

Comment: Oh crap, what happened to the spawn!?!?

Comment: A creeper blew it up.  NO, creeperS.

Comment: So I see :(((((

Comment: Repairing it now, BTW. Sorry :D

Comment: Spawn has been repaired, and ranks added.